# Recent Ubuntu update prevents MySQL root access

Tags: 10.04, updates, mysql, root

I recently updated my Ubuntu (10.04 LTS) server (apt-get update, apt-get upgrade), and everything works fine, apart from the root access to my MySQL database.

phpMyAdmin, CakePHP, and essentially all connections return similar access errors. For example, PMA returns 'Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.'

I have tried to find similar examples of this instance, but cannot find assistance in what configuration I should be changing to restore root log in access. The same issue has occurred on two servers. One has additional users so I could get around it, but the other is a new development server with only root MySQL access, so I am stuck on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out the error was the write access level for the my.cnf file for MySQL. Changing this to 644 and restarting MySQL fixed it up.